# My array is not showing in the Visual Studio Code console

Tags: javascript, arrays, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with **Visual Studio Code** console.

```
let array2D = [
    ["Mark", "Jeff", "Bezos"],
    ["Zuckerberg" , "bezos", "Gates,"]
];
array2D.splice(2, 0, ["45", "56", "37"]);
console.log(array2D);
```

Displayed in the console:

[image: consoleimage]

But in Webstorm there is no problem **Webstorm result** :

```
[
  [ 'Mark', 'Jeff', 'Bezos' ],
  [ 'Zuckerberg', 'bezos', 'Gates,' ],
  [ '45', '56', '37' ]
]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can i have the same result in Visual Code ?

thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: check the `output` tab, unless you're using the debugger - but, if you have WebStorm, stick with it - it is 100% (and a much better IDE)

Comment: You should be in the `Terminal` tab and run `node filename.js`

Comment: @RandyCasburn yeah i think im gonna use Webstorm more than Visual Code

Comment: @Samathingamajig Thank you so much it works!  i dont know why  the terminal works usually but here he was broken

Comment: You're not using a terminal there. It's some kind of built in JS running thingy. It looks like you need to configure it to work with a "debugger". Whatever it means by that. WebStorm is very powerful and well configured out the box. I would recommend using it instead anyway.

Comment: that panel operates the same as the Browser console.